# how to delete workorders in maximo

Tags: maximo

In maximo, can we delete a work order? The select action menu gives me

> BMXAA4612E - Cannot delete because it is, or had at one time been approved.

I have created numerous test work orders and it is getting difficult to track new work orders.

Comment: Could you provide exactly what maximo is ? There seems be numerous application named Maximo. Also, a better option would be to contact the support team of this application.

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp, Maximo is a highly configurable enterprise-class system for managing assets. It is composed of many applications, each of which can be used by different people in the enterprise for managing different, but related, data. You should click on the [maximo] tag, then follow the Learn more... link, and then follow the link to the Maximo Homepage.

Comment: @AntoineGrandchamp, there are lots of videos on YouTube about IBM Maximo. [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gjFkPpXVYhQ) shows a fellow working with the PM, Job Plan and Labor applications.

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: You can't.

Standard Maximo will not let you delete it past a certain point. It keeps this data around for a sort of auditing (and because there could be *a lot* of dependencies to undo).

Bad Answer: With some database queries. You can of course delete about anything if you start modifying Maximo's underlying database directly. The Work Order object has a number of related tables though, so make sure you delete all referenced data from those as well. And there might be other places you need to update too, like a PM due date, depending on the situation.

In a normal Maximo environment, it is very common to have a lot of open work orders at any given time. You are going to need to develop ways to handle the fluff. Closing your old test work orders helps, because Maximo filters out closed work orders by default. Standard filters with some specialized data and saved queries are some other options.

Answer (score 0):

Clear attribute: FIRSTAPPRSTATUS

update woactivity set FIRSTAPPRSTATUS = null
where ;

Then deleting should be possible
--> However it is not (in maximo 7.6)

Answer (score 0):

For Maximo 7.6, change the workorder status to WAPPR from the backend or through MIF and then use MIF to delete the record(s)

Answer (score 0):

I created an action that executes set FIRSAPPRSTATUS null and created an escalation with the condition of selecting a work order. After the escalation is completed, deletion will be available if the remaining conditions for deleting the work order are met.